# trouble acsessing values from class

Tags: swift, class, initialization

i am learning swift atm and the use of classes kept me busy the last two weeks.

thank you for any help

for a project in xcode i created a swift file containing a class that initializes empty strings/arrays of strings. 
then a function in that class is retrieving data from google firebase to fill those strings.

than in a viewcontroller class is want to retrieve those two strings. how do it do it right?
so far i tried many different ideas but i either get empty strings (as initialized in the beginning of the class) or i get errors

ideally everytime the viewdidload() (in this case) of the viewcontroller class is called i want it to create an instance of the class with uptodate data.

```
class RetrieveDatabase {

    //static let sharedInstance = RetrieveDatabase()

    var allMessages = [[String]]()
    var messages = [String]()
    var categorieNames = [String]()

    func loadGoogleValue() -> (allMessages: [[String]], categorieNames: [String]) {

        //this function works, the arrays contain type [string] and string                                                                                        
        return (self.allMessages, self.categorieNames)
    }

    /*
    -> i tried initializers in so many variations...
    init(allMessages: [[String]], categorieNames: [String]) {
        self.allMessages = loadGoogleValue().allMessages
        self.categorieNames = loadGoogleValue().categorieNames
        messages = []
    }
    */

}
```

here the code from the viewcontroller class:

```
class SettingsView: UIViewController {
     let retrieveDatabase = RetrieveDatabase.//tried everything here, only errors

     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        label1.text = retrieveDatabase.categorieNames[0]
    }
}
```

Comment: cmon guys? anyone?

Comment: Why don't you declare `retrieveDatabase` variable like this? `let retrieveDatabase = RetrieveDatabase()`

Comment: thank you for your reply, the strings are still both empty when called...

Comment: I'm just asked that to make sure there are no syntax errors. Where is the place you assign values to variables that you want to access?

Comment: inside the function loadGoogleValue(). the function works fine. i tried the following. still prints empty.
        

`let retrieveDatabase = RetrieveDatabase()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        print(retrieveDatabase.loadGoogleValue().allMessages)
        print(retrieveDatabase.loadGoogleValue().categorieNames)

    }`

wow this looks ugly

Answer (score 0):

I've simplified your code to something that you can easily try out in a playground.  If you start with a working version, perhaps you can see the difference between it and the one that's giving you trouble.

```
class RetrieveDatabase {
    var allMessages = [[String]]()
    var messages = [String]()
    var categorieNames = [String]()

    init() {
        messages.append("Hi")
        messages.append("Hello")
        allMessages.append(messages)
        categorieNames.append("SALUTATIONS")
    }

    func loadGoogleValue() -> (allMessages: [[String]], categorieNames: [String]) {
        return (self.allMessages, self.categorieNames)
    }
}

class SettingsView {
    let retrieveDatabase = RetrieveDatabase()

    func caller() {
        print(retrieveDatabase.loadGoogleValue().allMessages)
        print(retrieveDatabase.loadGoogleValue().categorieNames)
    }
}

let test = SettingsView().caller()
```

Since there's very little difference between what I've done and the code you added in your comment above, I suspect it's something you've left out concerning how strings are added to the arrays.

Comment: thank you. so i found the problem.
the loadgooglevalue func is async with my code. it works as in it does create the strings with the data from firebase but the function doesnt wait for it and just returns the empty strings.
im pretty new to programming so ill spend the afternoon trying to understand async programming. goal for the day: make this work!
thanks again and sorry for the hustle.